# working with radio buttons passing the status along with value?

Tags: javascript, php, html, radio-button

I am writing code for radio buttons where there are 3 radio buttons like YES, NO and ALL. I am using same class name for all the 3 and also binding a value for them. If user clicks on one of the three Am able to pass the corresponding value on onclick event but my problem is how to know whether user clicks on which radion button among the three buttons like if user clicks on 'All' radio button I want to perform some type of action else if user clicks on 'Yes' option then some different action, etc. how to know user clicks on which radio button? mycode is below:

```
<input type="radio" name="select_option" class="select_option" value="<?=$row_id;?>">All
<input type="radio" name="select_option" class="select_option" value="<?=$row_id;?>">Yes
<input type="radio" name="select_option" class="select_option" value="<?=$row_id;?>">No
```

I need radio button value along with user clicked on which radio button. how to achieve this? Can anyone please guide me.

Comment: Your all radio buttons values are same. Pass different values for each radio button. Then you can get selected radio button value in php

Comment: @B.Desai  *Aye*, so true. However, the OP seems to be working with a database. If their row(s) contains `Yes, No, All` in the same row (comma separated values) where their database was not normalized, then that could be it and introduces a bigger problem. One can use that method, but it's not recommended. Who knows what they have and what the real issue is/solution.

Comment: This question is way too unclear. What are your real values in your database and will you be answering to these comments, or are you only responding to "answers"? If not, then keep at it with the answers given. Voted to close as unclear.

Comment: ok our project has list of modules which come from database dynamically then we are giving user an option whether he clicks on 'All' (or) 'Yes' (or) 'No' option to select each module. I am passing each module's id in radio button as a value to manipulate it in javascript.

Comment: just like the first comment stated; your radio buttons all obviously hold the same value. Without knowing what `$row_id` is and what the database schema/values look like, then we can't help you. You will need to keep at it with the answers given; I will pass on this one, good luck.

Comment: Please review my answer & let me know, if you have any query.

Comment: 2 solutions which were answered by Pandiyan & Prateek Verma worked for me, I am getting confused to whom should I vote..!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add an extra parameter for storing the 'id' inside the input box, just like this:

```
<input type="radio" name="select_option" class="select_option" value="all" data-id="<?=$row_id;?>">All
<input type="radio" name="select_option" class="select_option" value="yes" data-id="<?=$row_id;?>">Yes
<input type="radio" name="select_option" class="select_option" value="no" data-id="<?=$row_id;?>">No
```

Now, here is the script which will run after checking the radio button:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.select_option').click(function() {
        if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
            var id = $(this).data('id');
            var value = $(this).val();
        }
       alert(value);
    });
});
</script>
```

I hope, this may be useful to you.

Comment: Thanks Prateek, Your solution also worked for me. I am getting confused to whom should I vote becoz Pandiyan solution also worked for me..

Comment: I am glad, it helped you. Do one thing, the solution which is more suitable to you mark it as right and vote for other right answers, so that others who are in great need could find most appropriate answer, thanks.

Comment: Thanks Prateek, I am giving vote for you. can u plz also tell what is the use of "data-" property of HTML elements? I know that use becoz I used that property for modal's like while edit data to fetch information and show them in the popup modal but I don't know we cam use like this also which you said in the solution.

Comment: 'data-*' is mainly used for storing the custom data, because sometimes you need to contain more data in any html tag more than id or class, so that's why it can be used globally in mostly html tags. For more information, visit here: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp.  I hope, it may be helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

I have added my class names(all, yes, no) in those html elements

```
<input type="radio" name="select_option" class="select_option all" value="<?=$row_id;?>">All
<input type="radio" name="select_option" class="select_option yes" value="<?=$row_id;?>">Yes
<input type="radio" name="select_option" class="select_option no" value="<?=$row_id;?>">No
```

Using jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("input:radio").click(function(e){

        if($(this).hasClass("all"))
        {
                console.log("which button -> all");
                console.log("value="+$(this).val());
        }
        else if($(this).hasClass("yes"))
        {
                console.log("which button -> yes");
                console.log("value="+$(this).val());
        }
        else if($(this).hasClass("no"))
        {
                console.log("which button -> no");
                console.log("value="+$(this).val());
        }
  });
});
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/2fkv9xht/3/)

Comment: Thanks, Your solution worked for me. But I have to check @Prateek Verma's solution also.

Comment: Thanks for your effort Pandiyan much appreciated. I am giving one "up vote" for you but not giving as a right answer becoz I felt Prateek's solution is more suitable to my requirement. Thank you once again :)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(".select_option").change(function(){
        var radioValue = $("input[name='select_option']:checked").val();
        if(radioValue){
            alert("Your are clicked - " + radioValue);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".select_option").change(function () {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        var value = $(this).val();
        console.log(value);
    }
});
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rushil_pachchigar/fw38hzdr/)

Comment: I can get the value but my question here is how to know if user clicked on which radio button among the three of 'All', 'Yes', 'NO'

Comment: you can use value variable for further process

Comment: I know that solution already. I am already passing a value dynamically withiin php tags as you can check in my above question. along with the value I need which radio button he is clicked.